# Olfden selling limits for magic Items

Tags: pathfinder-1e, golarion

I'm a bit confused about the entry of olfden in guide to the darkmoon vale.
Am I reading it correctly that:

- the highest magic Item available within olfden is 3k gold worth
- the maximum worth a magic Item being sold in olfden can get is 6.638 million gp?

(page 34 in that book)

or am I misreading the city statblock there and where can I get an info what each stat part means? (seen a few troubles with some being pathfindder some 3.5,...)

Answer (score 1):

The Guide to Darkmoon Vale was published during the 3.5 times. You're asking about the line in the settlement stat block reading

GP Limit 3,000 gp; Assets 6,638,000 gp

The "Community Wealth and Population" portion of the 3.5e DMG covers this (p.137). The gp limit is the price of the most valuable item available in the community, so things under that are likely available. To figure out ready cash for the community to buy stuff, you'd take half the gp limit times 1/10 of the population. The Assets line isn't really helpful, it's the value of the whole village.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently published in [2008](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1601251009), shortly after Wizards of the Coast transitioned to *Dungeons and Dragons, 4th Edition*, it appears that the *Pathfinder* Chronicles entry [*Guide to Darkmoon Vale*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy83yv?Pathfinder-Chronicles-Guide-to-Darkmoon-Vale) contains artifacts of *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* that had yet to receive the touch of the *Pathfinder Role-playing Game*.

In contemporary *Pathfinder* campaigns, settlements have statistic blocks that include a [Base Value and Purchase Limit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/settlements):

> This section lists the community's base value for available magic items in gp (see Table: Available Magic Items). There is a 75% chance that any item of this value or lower can be found for sale in the community with little effort. If an item is not available, a new check to determine if the item has become available can be made in 1 week. A settlement's purchase limit is the most money a shop in the settlement can spend to purchase any single item from the PCs. If the PCs wish to sell an item worth more than a settlement's purchase limit, they'll either need to settle for a lower price, travel to A larger city, or (with the GM's permission) search for a specific buyer in the city with deeper pockets. A settlement's type sets its purchase limit.

I suggest that the DM update Olfden's statistics to reflect the newer *Pathfinder* paradigm; in *Pathfinder* terms it's a Large Town.

If that's not an option, one must go back to the *Dungeon Master's Guide* for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* and look up Generating Towns:

> Every community has a gold piece limit based on its size and population. The gold piece limit... is an indicator of the price of the most expensive item available in that community. Nothing that costs more than a community’s gp limit is available for purchase in that community. Anything having a price under that limit is most likely available, whether it be mundane or magical. ... To determine the amount of ready cash in a community, or the
>   total value of any given item of equipment for sale at any given time, multiply half the gp limit by 1/10 of the community’s population. (137)

The statistics the *Guide* provides means that PCs in Olfden can buy individual items worth no more than 3,000 gp and can't make transactions in the community totaling more than 6,638,000 gp... which is a lot. The DM's supposed to keep track of the town's wealth, subtracting purchases the PCs makes from what's available until the town's bled dry, but I've never seen a DM go to that much trouble unless mechanically trying to make PCs move on to bigger adventures.

Comment: That means these old entries don't have the purchase limit but instead only use a "town limit"?
(I'm the dm btw so I need to think how to best do this without the players having a free go to sell a 1 mio artefact without having to search for someone who CAN buy it for a bit)

Comment: @ThomasE. Pretty much. But what *that* means is several hundred--or *thousand*--folks pooling *all* of their assets to *share ownership* of a single artifact, an unlikely occurrence that has *so many* role-playing possibilities, I'd let it happen (of course, *assets* means the PC likely wouldn't get 1 million gp in cash, either, but in property, animals, trade goods, and so on--in other words, more adventure fodder). Also, allowing PCs to sell artifacts--which normally lack gp sale values--is the DM's call. Nobody knows the fair prices for them; better to get something besides cash for them.